# Issue when implementing a Node class

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the following code ? I am trying to implement
a graph with a class Node which contains the node id and a vector of pointer to its neighbors. Here is a short version of my code :

```
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;


class N {
public:
    int i;
    vector<N*> v;
    N(int i) {
        this->i = i;
    };
};

int init(N* n1) {
    N n2(2);
    cout << "pointer " << &n2 << endl;
    n1->v.push_back(&n2);
};

int main() {
    N n1(1);
    init(&n1);
    cout << n1.i << endl;
    cout << "pointer " << n1.v[0] << endl;
    cout << n1.v.at(0)->i << endl;
    return 0;
};
```

The problem is that after the call to the init function, it seems that the node n2 does not exist anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What happens when you run your program? How does the output differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `n2` is local variable, which will be released after the `init` function call.  Therefore after the `init` function call, the content reside in its previous address is undefined.

To fix this issue, consider using the `new` operator:

```
int init(N* n1) {
    N* n2 = new N(2);
    cout << "pointer " << n2 << endl;
    n1->v.push_back(n2);
};
```

Or simply

```
int init(N* n1) {
    n1->v.push_back(new N(2));
};
```

Since the instance you added are created by the `new` operator, you need to release their memory by using the `delete` operator (for example, in `N`'s destructor):

```
~N() {
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    delete v[i];
  }
  v.clear();
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that any variables created with `new` must be deleted using `delete` otherwise your program will have memory leaks.

Comment: @DavidFreitag: thank you for your reminder.  I have include it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
int init(N* n1) {
    N n2(2);
    cout << "pointer " << &n2 << endl;
    n1->v.push_back(&n2);

} // life time of n2 ends here
```

`n2` resides on stack. Its life time ends as soon as init returns. So having a reference to it results in undefined behavior. Try -

```
n1->v.push_back(new N(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about scope. `n2` goes out of scope (and therefore its memory address) at the end of the function `init`